# connecting to internet via another PC

Tags: internet, lan, switch, gateway

Not sure if this is the right place to ask this question

Currently i have this set up

PC 1 and PC 2 are connected by a switch on the same subnet which is connected to a router.

I would like to connect to internet via this route

PC 1 - > PC 2 -> router

However, i tried configuring my default gateway and DNS address as the ip address of PC2 but it does not work.

I am using windows 7 and have disabled firewall on PC 2

Answer (score 0):

ICS Internet connection sharing is what you're after, below is the link to Microsoft instructions to enable it and use it. It's fairly easy to set up.
[Click me](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/using-internet-connection-sharing#1TC=windows-7)